# Rendering grid in React using lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I struggle to render a simple grid for my test project. 
Didn't want to create grid by hand, because with bigger grids that would not only be a chore, but also the code would be cluttered, so figured I should use lodash for this.

However, I can't seem to render the grid, it's just not visible even when I inspect in dev tools. Can someone point my mistakes?

I am also fine with using other tools than lodash if necessary.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import './game.css';


const GRID = [
    [{x: 1, y:3}, {x:2, y:3}, {x:3,y:3}],
    [{x: 1, y:2}, {x:2, y:2}, {x:3,y:2}],
    [{x: 1, y:1}, {x:2, y:1}, {x:3,y:1}],
]
class Game extends React.Component {
    renderGrid() {
      return _.map(GRID, row =>{
            _.map(row, cell =>{
                return <div style={{height: 100 + 'px', width: 100+ 'px'}}> {cell.x}, {cell.y} </div>
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="game">
                {this.renderGrid()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Game;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the inner map result, once you do that it will work

```
renderGrid() {
      return _.map(GRID, row =>{
           return  _.map(row, (cell, index) =>{
                return <div key={index} style={{height: 100 + 'px', width: 100+ 'px'}}> {cell.x}, {cell.y} </div>
            })
        })
    }
```

[Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/2pl3j44qwj)

Comment: Indeed you were right, to make it a grid I also had to wrap every row in grid and give it a proper class. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the array buildin `map` function should be enough.
Don't forget give an unique key for each element in the map

**Tips:**

- `items.map(item => item)` is the short hand format for `items.map(item => { return(item); })`
- If you put number in inline css style, 'px' unit will be used as default.

Based on your input:

```js
class Game extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
      {
        GRID.map((row, rowIdx) => (
          row.map((cell, cellIdx) => (
            <div 
              key={`${rowIdx}-${cellIdx}`}
              style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }} 
            >
            {cell.x}, {cell.y}
            </div>
          ))
        ))
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

There is the codesandbox demo for this code: https://codesandbox.io/s/2px4znwopr

Hope this answer could help.

Comment: It also works, thanks, dont know why I pushed lodash

Comment: I like to import as minimal package as possible, but most likely lodash will be used by anther packages anyway. So this is purely depend on your preference. BTW, if you take a look on lodash source code, it basically a wrapper of default map method.

Answer (score 0):

Full solution to render a grid using bootstrap:

```
 renderGrid() {
        return _.map(GRID, row => {
            return <div className="row"> {_.map(row, cell => {
                return <div style={{ height: 100 + 'px', width: 100 + 'px' }}> {cell.x}, {cell.y} </div>
            })
            } </div>
        })
    }
```